# Numerical sequence of 1 2 4

Tags: algorithm, loops, for-loop, sequence, fibonacci

I need help in providing an algorithm for a numerical sequence which should display a series of 1 2 4 and its consecutive summations.

e.g. If my input value is 20, it should display

> 1 2 4 8 9 11 15 16 18

Wherein

- 1 = 1
- 2 = 1 + 1
- 4 = 2 + 2
- 8 = 4 + 4

And the summation of 1 and 2 and 4 will repeat again starting with the present number which is 8 and so on..

- 9 = 8 + 1
- 11 = 9 + 2
- 15 = 11 + 4
- 16 = 15 + 1
- 18 = 16 + 2

As you can see, it should not proceed to 22 (18 + 4) since our sample input value is 20. I hope you guys get my point. I'm having a problem in designing the algorithms in the for loop. What I have now which is not working is

```
$input = 20;
for ($i = $i; $i < $input; $i = $i+$i) {
    if($i==0){
       $i = 4;
       $i = $i - 3;
    }elseif($i % 4 == 0){
       $i = $i + 1;
    }
    print_r("this is \$i = $i<br><br>");
}
```

**NOTE:** Only one **variable** and one **for loop** is required, it will not be accepted if we use functions or arrays. Please help me, this is one of the most difficult problems I've encountered in PHP..

Answer (score 0):

you can use the code

```
$input = 20;
$current = 1;
$val = 1;
while($val < $input){
    print_r("this is \$val = $val\n");
    $val = $val + $current;
    $current = ($current == 4 ? 1 : $current*2);
}
```

see the [online compiler](https://ideone.com/XJh33w)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have mentioned **Only one variable and one for loop is required**

Try this,

```
$input = 20;
for ($i = 1; $i < $input; $i) {
    if($i>$input) break;
    print_r("this is \$i = $i<br><br>");
    $i=$i+1;
    if($i>$input) break;
    print_r("this is \$i = $i<br><br>");
    $i=$i+2;
    if($i>$input) break;
    print_r("this is \$i = $i<br><br>");
    $i=$i+4;
}
```

[Online Compiler](https://ideone.com/W3wUOF)

Answer (score 0):

```
def getSeq(n):
    if n == 1:
        return [1]
    temp = [1]
    seq = [ 1, 2, 4]
    count, current, prev = 0, 0, 1
    while True:
        current = prev + seq[count]
        if current > n:
            break
        prev = current
        temp += [current]
        count = (count + 1) % 3
    return temp
print getSeq(20)
```

I'm pretty sure that this one is going to work

the case that we have to take care of is **n == 1** and return a static result [1].

in other cases the second value is repeating circularly and adding up to previous value.

Answer (score 0):

This Python solution should be implementable in any reasonable language:

```
limit = 20

n = 1 << 2

while n >> 2 < limit:
    print(n >> 2)
    n = (((n >> 2) + (2 ** (n & 3))) << 2) + ((n & 3) + 1) % 3
```

**Perl Equivalent** (using the style of `for` loop you expect):

$limit = 20;

```
for ($n = 1 << 2; $n >> 2 < $limit; $n = ((($n >> 2) + (2 ** ($n & 3))) << 2) + (($n & 3) + 1) % 3) {
    print($n >> 2, "\n");
    }
```

**OUTPUT**

```
1
2
4
8
9
11
15
16
18
```

**EXPLANATION**

The basic solution is this:

```
limit = 20

n = 1
i = 0

while n < limit:
    print(n)
    n = n + (2 ** i)
    i = (i + 1) % 3
```

But we need to eliminate the extra variable `i`.  Since `i` only cycles through 0, 1 and 2 we can store it in two bits.  So we shift `n` up two bits and store the value for `i` in the lower two bits of `n`, adjusting the code accordingly.

Not only one variable and one `for` loop, no `if` statements either!